# jQuery + Spring- AJAX FormData submission returning null with request.getParameter

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

So, my form looks something like this:

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="upload-form" action="">
    <select class="form-control" name="category" style="margin: 0.5em">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My JavaScript code is this:

```
$("button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: '/pos/csvUpload,
        data: new FormData(document.getElementById("upload-form")),
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST'
    });

    // request callbacks...
});
```

And my Java code handles it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pos/csvUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> csvUpload(Model model,
                            MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response
) throws Exception
{
    String category = request.getParameter("category");
    ...
}
```

(Notice I have MultipartHttpServletRequest; it's necessary for me because I have a file input in there that uses that class to parse it.)

As I look through tutorials and more SO posts online, they all tell me to use request.getParameter. However, when I use it, it returns `null`.

1. I'm using the FormData class
2. I'm using AJAX to send the FormData over
3. I'm using Spring MVC
4. I'm using the MultipartHttpServletRequest class

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **listBox**, use HttpServletRequest#getParameter**Values**(),
which will return an **array** of values instead of single value.

You can refer java doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String[] category = request.getParameterValues("category");
```

Comment: But I only want the value of the option selected. What do I do with the array?

Comment: I carefully read your code, With the available information, everything else looks good, but i doubted in this line. If this also returns null, then the problem might be somewhere else which is not available in this question.

Comment: "but I doubted in this line". What do you mean? You doubt your answer?

Comment: OK, but my question is, how do I get the value of the **selected** option in the dropdown?

Comment: You can ignore this answer, if you don't want to try, bye.

Comment: No, but I am going to try it. But I only want one particular String; the value of the option selected. Your answer gives me a String[], so how do I know which of these values is the one I'm looking for?

Comment: Step 1 can be checking whether this array contains any value or null, if this also null, you can think for other solution, if that array returns any value, let's think Step2. btw chat banned here in my company.